# handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification will not fire. iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, swift2, appdelegate

I am trying to test my app and I noticed that handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification does not fire.  While the app is in the foreground, this delegate method should fire after the user clicks on the action. I have read other posts about this, but most of them refer to the completionHandler() at the bottom of the method.  I cannot seem to find a solution. If I put my app in the background, didReceiveLocalNotification does fire correctly. I am truly stumped.  Here is my code...

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let notificationActionOk = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    notificationActionOk.identifier = "ALARM_IDENTIFIER"
    notificationActionOk.title = "Ok"
    notificationActionOk.destructive = false
    notificationActionOk.authenticationRequired = false
    notificationActionOk.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

    let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    notificationCategory.identifier = "ALARM_CATEGORY"
    notificationCategory.setActions([notificationActionOk], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    notificationCategory.setActions([notificationActionOk], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: [notificationCategory])
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    print("Handle action \(identifier)")
    completionHandler()
    //I cannot get this method to fire.
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Received local notification")
    //This method fires correctly
}

}
```